# unable to enter a mac address: libreoffice calc 5.1.2.2 Ubuntu

Tags: libreoffice-calc

When entering a mac address in a text cell:

00:10:00:10:00:10

Each 00:10 is automatically converted to a time.
I've been unable to turn this via cell format, other settings suggested by search results ...

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Kent

Answer (score 0):

that doesn't happen here (using Libreoffice calc 5.1.3.2 on Kubuntu). If I type in that mac address into a cell, calc interprets it as a string. I tried this with a cell formatted as text, and as no format (Number > General).

Otherwise, you could try by preceding the string with a single quote mark '. This should force calc to interpret the contents as a string.

Answer (score 0):

fixed via:
Tools -> AutoCorrect Options -> uncheck "Use replacement table"

Numbers surrounded by : are replaced by the clock icon.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this, but it doesn't really answer the OP's question. Thanks a lot for the tip, though!